# Force HTML 5 video bar (with volume, progress, etc) to appear in Chrome with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, html5-video

Using javascript, we can easily play an html5 video with `vid.play()`, seek with `vid.currentTime = x`, etc. However, on screen, the video just jumps to a new time without any indication where it jumped to; what I'd like is for the progress bar to appear on the video for a few seconds displaying the current time and total video duration, just like if the user had clicked play or seeked along the bar with the mouse. Is there any way to do this in code?

This is probably very browser specific and that's OK, I'm only doing it for personal use in Chrome

Comment: Does the `controls` attribute work for you? E.g. [this first example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Comment: The controls attribute includes the controls bar when you mouse over the video or pause it, but it doesn't appear when you seek in code, change the volume in code, etc.